# Topology on vector space such that vector operations are not continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

everyone

I am reading about distribution theory and the first concept is topological vector space. The definition says it is a topological vector space if its topology keeps the two vector operations, i.e., the vector addition and scalar multiplication continuous. I am trying to find a topology on a vector space that does not keeps this continuity property. Unluckily I don't find a convincing one.

Comment: Tried integers and some wierd topologies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the topology on $\Bbb R$ in which the set is open iff it's empty or contains $1$.

To prove scalar multiplication is discontinuous, let $\alpha$ be any scalar different from $0,1$. Then letting $f:x\mapsto \alpha x$, the preimage of open set $\{1\}$ is $\{\frac{1}{\alpha}\}$, which isn't open.

To prove addition is discontinuous, consider $f:(x,y)\mapsto x+y$. Then the preimage of $\{1\}$ under $f$ is the set $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:x+y=1\}$. We need to show the last set is not open. But it's easy to see that in the product topology, if a set $A\subseteq\Bbb R^2$ is open then it is empty or contains $(1,1)$, while our preimage is nonempty and doesn't contain $(1,1)$.

Comment: @Hua I have added details as to why the operations are discontinuous.

Comment: I think the second part is right, except a typo that $A \subseteq  R^2$. Regarding the first part, I don't think it is appropriate to rule out 0 and 1 from a scalar field.

Comment: @Hua Unfortunatelly, this is the best we can get when it comes to scalar multiplication.  For $\alpha=1$, we get identity, which is clearly continuous no matter what topology you take. For $\alpha=0$, preimage of every set containing $0$ is whole space, hence open, and preimage of set not containing $0$ is empty, hence open. So we can't find a topology in which $x\mapsto\alpha x$ is discontinuous for $\alpha=0$ or $1$.

Comment: Yes, I think so. There is a typo in your second part. I cannot edit unless the edit is more than 6 characters.

Comment: I have already fixed the typo you have mentioned. Or do you mean there is another typo?

Comment: No, that is OK up to now. Maybe I didn't refresh the page

Answer (score 3):

Take $\mathbb R$ with the topology generated by the intervals of the form $[a,b)$.

Comment: I think this is a possible answer. Do you mind giving more details?

Comment: Like why it makes the operations discontinuous. I have an idea as I mentioned above. I want to know what you think:-)

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused. Take -1 for what? I think the preimage of [a,b) by vector addition is $\{(x,y): x+y=z, z\in [a,b)\}$, which can be covered by union of [a,b)*[c,d), i.e., it is open. So I think it is continuous. I changed my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\phi\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be some crazy bijection. For specificity, you could take $\phi(x)=x$ for $x\not\in\{0,1\}$ and $\phi(1)=0$, $\phi(0)=1$. We give $\mathbb R$ a new topology (and call it $\tilde{\mathbb R}$) so that $\phi\colon\tilde{\mathbb R}\to \mathbb R$ is a homeomorphism to the standard topology on the reals. The vector operations on $\tilde{\mathbb R}$ are not continuous.

In other words, the open sets of $\tilde {\mathbb R}$ are the open sets of $\mathbb R$ with $1$ and $0$ interchanged. So $(-1/2,1)\cup(1,1/2)\cup\{0\}$ is an open set in $\tilde {\mathbb R}$.

Comment: Oh, thanks for this answer. This is a new and interesting idea to me, but I am not familiar with the concept homeomorphism. It would be more helpful if you could say more.